# why use href as "#" in <a> anchor tag in HTML5?

Tags: html

I'm kind of a beginner to HTML,I was wondering why most of the web pages use "#" as a href value.
I've previously used href value for opening some other websites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of href="###" in anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455697/what-is-the-use-of-href-in-anchor-tag)

Comment: I have seen this technique when the anchor tab is used to fire a javascript events as opposed to open web pages

Answer (score 2):

When using # as a href value, the link will take you something that already exists in the site

Like this example below

```
<p>Click <a href="#intro">here</a></p>
<h1 id="intro">Introduction</h1>
```

Clicking on "here" will take you down to the "Introduction" heading

Comment: Thanks i undertood.

Answer (score 0):

"#" is used for internal link.

e.g.

```
#header, #footer.
```